# Difference between "undemonstrable" and "indemonstrable"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, usage

What is the difference between "undemonstrable" and "indemonstrable"? **Indemonstrable** has the meaning whereas the **undemonstrable** doesn't have. According to [Google NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undemonstrable%2Cindemonstrable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cundemonstrable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindemonstrable%3B%2Cc0) both the words are widely used but [Merriam webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undemonstrable) or [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=undemonstrable) doesn't provide the meaning.
[image: Ngram plot]

Which word is correct "undemonstrable" or "indemonstrable"? Do they have same meaning?

**EDIT:** This is what I got when I searched in Merriam-webster.
[image: Merriam Webster screenshot]

And for Oxford dictionary
[image: Oxford Dictionaries screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indemonstrable

Comment: undemonstrable: [not able to be made evident](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/undemonstrable). indemonstrable: [incapable of being demonstrated or proved](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/indemonstrable). Both have meaning.

Comment: @Cardinal This is what I got in their website. Please have a look on the Question once again.

Comment: @ARYF I didn't mean you didn't search anything. I just want to mention MW has a definition. Perhaps I chose improper words bro.

Comment: What you provided is for "indemonstrable" not for "**undemonstrable**". Anyway thanks. Do you know the reason behind this? Why popular dictionaries like them do not add this words?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think dictionaries are of different types. Many of them are abridged and others are unabridged. The unabridged dictionaries encompass nearly all the words. I am not sure about the Online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Demonstrable*** just happens to be one of those words that doesn't have a well-established negating prefix (both ***un-*** and ***in-*** are used, with exactly the same meaning). But as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indemonstrable%2Cundemonstrable%2Ccannot%20be%20demonstrated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindemonstrable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cundemonstrable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20be%20demonstrated%3B%2Cc0) shows, native speakers don't much like either form - perhaps partly *because* of that uncertainty. We're much more likely to use alternative phrasing...

[image]

---

It may be worth comparing the full OED entry for...

> **indemonstrable**
>   [image]

...and...

> **undemonstrable**
>   [image]

Apart from the smaller number of citations, it may be significant that OED don't even bother to give the pronunciation for the latter (which has *mostly* been less common over the past two centuries).

Answer (score 1):

The prefixes "in" and "un" are defined in most dictionaries. In both the Oxford and the American Heritage dictionaries they are both defined as "not or the opposite of". Therefore "undemonstrable" and "indemonstrable" mean the same thing. The only difference between "in" and "un" is that "in" can be used with "adjectives and words formed from adjectives" and "un" can be used with "adjectives, adverbs, verbs, and nouns".